# Joomla 3.0 Component View (white screen of death)

Tags: component

I'm currently developing a simple component in Joomla 3 and I know  that I completely followed the instructions in the book I read. however when I navigate to the component I made only white screen was shown even the Joomla headers were not there and I also configured the server settings error reporting to maximum.

What are the possible problems or wrong doings I had done.

Comment: Please provide the error message you have.

Comment: white screen of death. no error messages shown just a plain page with white background.

Comment: Then you should check your `error.log` for error as was suggested.

Comment: Already fixed this issue by installing again the component.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience the most likely reason is a simple typo somewhere in the files. Use an editor that does syntax highlighting and **pay attention** to the colors. I think a typical bug would be forgetting the ending symbol in some block (quote, block, comment, parameter lis, line etc). Syntax highlighting should show that.